# xslt - store node after stripping the child

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

How do i store a node set to a variable, after removing one unwanted element? Example if the input xml

```
<we:head xmlns:we="http://etest">

<we:abc>123</we:abc>
<we:tst>fgh</we:tst>
<we:sub>
<df></df>
</we:sub>

</we:head>
```

I want the variable to have the below when accessed in xslt, sub should be removed

```
<we:head xmlns:we="http://etest">

<we:abc>123</we:abc>
<we:tst>fgh</we:tst>

</we:head>
```

Note that i am using xslt 1.0 and also i dont want this to be passed to output, should be able to access from the variable in xslt

Comment: You won't be able to do this in XSLT 1.0 without using an extension function like `exsl:node-set()` (from http://www.exslt.org/). Does your processor support exslt?

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said: Computing a temporary tree into a variable isn't difficult:

```
<xsl:variable name="foo">
    <!-- do whatever XSLT is needed here to produce the XML results -->
</xsl:variable>
```

But in XSLT 1.0, that will be a `result tree`. You can copy a result tree into the output, but you can't process it further in XSLT. To do that, you need to turn it into a `nodeset`, and the 1.0 spec didn't define a mechanism for doing so.

Many early processors added a custom extension function which can do so. Most current processors support the standardized [EXSLT `node-set()` extension function](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/), which has better odds of being portable.

XSLT 2.0 solved this by removing the distinction between `result trees` and `nodesets`, using the concept `temporary tree` to cover both. As a result, in 2.0 you can simply navigate against the variable without having to first convert it to a nodeset.

Comment: Will the below code work <xsl:variable name="node" select="//*[local-name()='head'] and not(//*[local-name()='head/*[local-name()='sub'])"/> Also i can use exsl:node-set() function